# (GWT) Errai compilation error message not helpful

Tags: java, gwt

Here's a sample Error message from Errai compilation:

```
[INFO]          Rule did not match
[INFO]          Found better fallback match for <replace-with class='com.google.gwt.logging.client.LogConfiguration.LogConfigurationImplRegular'/>
[INFO]          Checking rule <generate-with class='org.jboss.errai.marshalling.rebind.MarshallerGenerator'/>
[INFO]             Checking if all subconditions are true (<all>)
[INFO]                <when-assignable class='org.jboss.errai.marshalling.client.api.GeneratedMarshaller'/>
[INFO]                   Yes, the requested type was assignable
[INFO]                Yes: All subconditions were true
[INFO]          Rule was a match and will be used
[INFO]          Invoking generator org.jboss.errai.marshalling.rebind.MarshallerGenerator
[INFO]             Type 'org.jboss.errai.marshalling.client.api.Marshaller_a_j_l_StackTraceElement_D1_Impl' already exists and will not be re-created 
[INFO]             Generator returned type 'org.jboss.errai.marshalling.client.api.Marshaller_a_j_l_StackTraceElement_D1_Impl; mode USE_EXISTING; in 0 ms
[INFO]          Rebind result was org.jboss.errai.marshalling.client.api.Marshaller_a_j_l_StackTraceElement_D1_Impl
[INFO] Shutting down PersistentUnitCache thread
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 03:52 min
```

My question is how to get into the actual error that needs to be fixed or at least something more detailed.

Comment: That does not look like an error to me (apart from the `BUILD FAILURE` line)

Comment: Agreed - its not helpful, because it isn't an error message. Search higher up int he log, or turn down logging to TRACE or INFO rather than ALL. Something else failed earlier, or suddenly and wasnt logged (OOM? forked jvm killed?).

Comment: Haven't fixed the error but somehow I did a text search on the very long logs and searched for the entity / model names of my app and saw something about the field serialization